# phonegap +jquery mobile + JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova

I have a problem if i want to insert this json test into my phonegap page(which has jquery mobile included):

```
var JSONObject = {  "name" : "Amit",
                 "address"  : "B-123 Bangalow",
                 "age"  : 23, 
                 "phone"   : "011-4565763",
                 "MobileNo"  : 0981100092
             };

             document.write("<h2><font color='blue'>Name</font>::"
                            +JSONObject.name+"</h2>");  
             document.write("<h2><font color='blue'>Address</font>::"
                            +JSONObject.address+"</h2>");  
             document.write("<h2><font color='blue'>Age</font>::"
                            +JSONObject.age+"</h2>");  
             document.write("<h2><font color='blue'>Phone No.</font>::"
                            +JSONObject.phone+"</h2>");  
             document.write("<h2><font color='blue'>Mobile No.</font>::"
                            +JSONObject.MobileNo+"</h2>");
```

Then it doesn't work.. My question is, is JSON actually possible with phonegap+jquery mobile??

In the future i want a webservice which returns data in JSON format so that I can use this json data in my phonegap app.. I am now testing if json data works, by using hardcoded data..

Comment: That's not JSON. JSON is a language, not an object in javascript.

Comment: @Esailija JSON is a format, not a language.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa it *is* a language. Please don't link me to someone saying "JSON is a data interchange format". How does that not make it a language?

Comment: @Esailija Starting from wikipedia? "Douglas Crockford was the first to specify and popularize the JSON **format**"

Comment: HTML is a language. XML is a language. JSON is... wait, what?

Comment: my point was merely: don't ever ***TRUST*** wikipedia. it is edited and written by the public and in most cases it is correct, however it has been known to be wrong.

Comment: @rlemon While this is true, as you know wikipedia has a lot of reviewers. Anyway wikipedia is not the only source where you can find that JSON is a format not a language. Infact, I said "Starting from Wikipedia"

Comment: I'm not saying you are wrong, I'm just pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probable this code is called after the page has finished loading.

So there is no point in using document.write.

Simply use the [html](http://api.jquery.com/html/) function to fill what you want to fill (probably a div).

Note that you must wait for the DOM to be fully loaded. The best practice is to use the onload event handler and to put the script element at the end of the body.

```
<div id=idOfTheDivWhereYouWantToWrite></div>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var JSONObject = {  "name" : "Amit",
             "address"  : "B-123 Bangalow",
             "age"  : 23, 
             "phone"   : "011-4565763",
             "MobileNo"  : 0981100092
    };
    var html= "<h2><font color='blue'>Name</font>::"+JSONObject.name+"</h2>" 
    html += "<h2><font color='blue'>Address</font>::" +JSONObject.address+"</h2>";  
    html += "<h2><font color='blue'>Age</font>::" +JSONObject.age+"</h2>";  
    html += "<h2><font color='blue'>Phone No.</font>::"+JSONObject.phone+"</h2>";  
    html += "<h2><font color='blue'>Mobile No.</font>::"+JSONObject.MobileNo+"</h2>";
    $('#idOfTheDivWhereYouWantToWrite').html(html);
});
</script>
```

Besides, a "JSON object" doesn't mean much as JSON is an exchange format. This is just a plain javascript object.

Comment: Is json possible with phonegap, im developing an ios app using phonegap

Comment: Yes but there is no JSON in your question. Try to explain what you want to do in the question.

Comment: Do you have a div with id "idOfTheDivWhereYouWantToWrite" ?

Comment: no i did it i a <span id="...">, edit: just did it with div but also no result

Comment: i have more than one page, isn't that a problem within phonegap to use document.ready on multiple pages?